# how to get specific files from a folder in asp.net (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, directoryinfo

I want to get all the files from a folder using DirectoryInfo, how can i perform check and get all the images from the folder, 
For checking i want to pass a productid as all the images are saved with their productids, for instance a product (bmw) has a product id 100 ,

Any ideas or tutorials of how to workout this.
Your help will be appreciated .

Comment: I assume you just suggested the use of DirectoryInfo and that it wasn't a requirement to actaully use it if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a searchfilter when using Directory.GetFiles with wildcards in it

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\", string.Format("{0}*.jpg", productId)
```

The * in the searchFilter is a wildcard. Anything that matches the first part which is the productId and ends with .jpg is going to match the filtering criteria

This function will return a list of strings of all the matching files. In the result you will have the full path to each file.

The filter above would match all of these if the productId is set to "101":
101_1.jpg
101_10.jpg
101_100.jpg

but would not match because the first part of the criteria is not fullfilled then.
100_1.jpg

Comment: i cant hard code 100 as the product id changes for different products

Comment: I made a quick edit on a suggested solution using string.Format to put the product id into the search

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge :(

Comment: Also if i have images like 100_1 , 100_2 , where hundred is the product id and the following numbers is the number of images which can be upto 10 as 10 images are allowed, how can i search that , do i have to runna loop and pass that loop value

Comment: Will it also save the it in a list or array , as i will pass these to an image slider using for each

Comment: Also the visual studio is giving error at @ Expression expected

Comment: You can remove the @ in front of the `@"c:\"` statement; this is C# syntax that isn't needed for VB.

Answer (score 0):

as you know you will be passing the productid, and filename is a string
so you can always check filename.substring(0,3)== your productid
if it is same then the correct images for that proudct id are saved